# Branch and Bound: How to determine Lower Bound Cost

Tags: algorithm, branch-and-bound

I want to write a program to solve a board game.
In this game, there are two boards. One is source board S. Another one is target board T. My goal is to move pieces in the board S so that they appear the same as in the board T **with smallest number of moves**. Each time I can move one item only. In addition, I can move an item to an adjacent space only ("~" denote the space). There may more than one "~". So I want to use Branch and Bound algorithm to solve this problem. However I have no idea how to determine the lower bound cost (fewst moves to change current state to goal state).

[image: board T and board S]

Comment: Are you interested in these specific boards, or a more general problem space?

Comment: I'm not just intersted in these specific boards. There are different boards will be provided. The size of board will between 3*3 to 10 * 10. The item of the board may include ~, K, Q, R, G, B, P.